# R:Replace all values in a list according to rules in other dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to replace all values in a list (An) with their respective values in another dataframe.

```
String<-c("a","b","c")
Strn<-1:length(String)                            
LK<-data.frame(String,Strn)
An<-as.vector(permn(length(Strn)))
```

I've created a simple example above with only 3 elements, but I have a much lager and more diverse  list in my data (hence a simple ifelse recode would be too long) . So here I want "a" to be replaced with 1, b with 2 and c with 3 across the whole list because these are the "rules" found in LK.

Is there a way to tell R: look at each element in An, find a match in LK$Strn and replace An  with LK$String ?

So the beginning of resulting list will be

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "b" "c"

[[2]]
[1] "a" "c" "b"
```

Obviously the full resulting list will be the same size as An.

I've tried `match()` but I must be doing something wrong...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a quick lapply like so...

```
res <- lapply( An , function(x){ x <- as.character( LK[ match( x , LK$Strn ) , "String" ] ) } )

    res
#   [[1]]
#   [1] "a" "b" "c"

#   [[2]]
#   [1] "a" "c" "b"

#   [[3]]
#   [1] "c" "a" "b"

#   [[4]]
#   [1] "c" "b" "a"

#   [[5]]
#   [1] "b" "c" "a"

#   [[6]]
#   [1] "b" "a" "c"
```

Comment: you can simplify the function in a general case as: `lapply(An, function(x) letters[x])`. Or here, `lapply(An, function(x) String[x])`

Comment: @Arun very nice. I wish I'd thought of that, but it does depend on a = 1 , b =2 etc, always being true. (which it probably is).